# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10: which device for boot loader installation (BIOS install)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, bootloader

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD, and storage on my HDD. I've gone through the Ubuntu installer and created the partitions (/home etc on HDD and /, /usr on SSD), which I believe is about right.

Now it asks for a boot loader installation, which I thought would be my SSD (/sdb). However, it says the Windows 10 (loader) is on the HDD, /sda, and I thought the two loaders would have to be together.

So, which should be the device for boot loader installation?
[image: sda]
[image: sdb]

Comment: I'm guessing, due to the size of Windows 10 (loader), this is just a recovery loader of an image produced earlier. As Windows 10 is still on the SSD (/sdb1), I should still continue to boot via sdb. Is this correct?

Comment: With BIOS/MBR, you only can boot from MBR or the first sector on the hard drive. With two drives, you can keep Windows boot loader on Windows drive and Ubuntu boot loader on Ubuntu drive (sdb). Usually best not to have system folders as separate partitions, unless a server type install or an advanced user. You now have another partition to manage space available on. Regularly houseclean and check available remaining space.